# how can i add a "safe as svg" option to users for my inline svg spritesheet iconset

Tags: html, svg, save, icons, inline

i created a open source icon set what you can see here : https://fusion.li

as a designer, i can imagine users would love to drag out an icon from the website directly on the desktop or into a design programm and using it.

i wonder if  have any parameter or way to make it easy to save an icon from website. each icon dragable to desktop to save an icon directly from web to file - as i can do it with images - or have a right click to "save file as".